# Strapi new can only be called in an empty directory

Tags: strapi

I been trying to run Strapi new server on my visual studio terminal and just been having errors the errors says

> strapi new can only be called in an empty directory

I tried everything but nothing worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more details to help answer your question. What code do you have so far?

Answer (score -1):

Remove `strapi-app` directory from your root project if you want create new project by command: `strapi new strapi-app`.

This error mean that you have already project with name wich you try create.